# Longest Repeated (non-overlapping) Subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, subsequence

How to find the longest repeated (non-overlapping) subsequence (not substring)?

constraint:

> The string S consist of at most 100.000 lower case character 'a'-'z'.

example:

> String **hanadswomehanudsiome** has longest repeated (non-overlapping)
>   subsequence **handsome**.

The expected time complexity is O(|S| log |S|) or better (|S| is length of string S).

Comment: are you having trouble putting this into code?

Comment: no, I still don't get the algorithm.

Comment: Why do you think there's an O(N log N) solution? It seems unlikely given how similar this is to the longest-common-subsequence problem.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original problem (if possible), or else, please add more details to your question, for example, maximum number of character in the string, does the string only contains letter...?

Comment: Edited :)
Sorry for the unclear statement.

Comment: Dewangga, what is your N? Is it the length of the string? With your formulation the problem can be solved in O(1) because you have put an upper bound on the problem size.

Comment: There appear to be two plausible interpretations of 'non-overlapping' in the problem statement: The first (and much more likely) is that the first occurrence must end before the second begins. The other is that non-overlapping means only disjoint, but allows for possibly interwoven occurrences. These meanings coincide in the case of substrings. Is there any chance the second interpretation was meant?

Comment: The paper, "An Efficient Algorithm for the Longest Tandem Scattered Subsequence Problem" by Adrian Kosowski, seems to address this problem. I believe they conjecture O(n^2) is not possible to improve on.

Comment: @גלעדברקן That's an excellent reference paper. There's a trivial reduction from LCS to this problem that implies `O(n^2)` is the fastest possible, based on standard hardness assumptions on LCS (although this is a decades-old, heavily researched open problem in CS). The `O(n^2)` algorithm presented in that paper, however, seems highly nontrivial to come up with.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/longest-repeated-scattered-subsequence-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

The problem, defined in the language of computer science, is finding the longest common scattered sub-sequence (LCSS) that occurs at least twice without overlap in the input string.

This is a matter of ongoing research in computer science, and it is a sub-problem of the more general [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). In one form or another, solutions to this problem have been proposed going from 1977 ([Hunt-Szymanski algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93Szymanski_algorithm)) to the present day.

One of the more recent publications on the problem is ["Small Longest Tandem Scattered Subsequences" by Russo and Francisco](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353789499_Small_Longest_Tandem_Scattered_Subsequences). It claims this time complexity for the algorithm:

```
O(min{n, ℓ}λ(1 + log(min{λ, ℓ/λ})) + nλ + ℓ)
```

Where:

- `n` is the size of the input string
- `λ` is the size of the longest common scattered sub-sequence
- `ℓ` is the number of pairs of positions in the input string that contain the same letter

However, for a constrained input size, the time complexity collapses to `O(1)` as was pointed out in the comments.